# Please, Let me know this approximation

Tags: approximation

$$    
N_v = 0.5(t^{2}+2t^{6/7})\ln(1+2t^{-8/7})-t^{6/7}  \tag{1}  
$$
$$
    N_v =(0.871+0.125\ln t)^2 \tag{2}$$
Eq(2) is the approximated version of Eq(1).
Does anyone know how to derive (2) from (1)?
I'd appreciate your intuiton.

Comment: Are you sure these equations are well given?, because if my calculations are correct the 1st one doesn't verify the 2nd.

Comment: For what range of $t$ is this approximation supposed to hold?

Comment: i think range of t is 0.001<t<1

Answer (score 1):

The two formulas are pretty close (within about .03) for $t$ in an interval from about $.0002$ to $0.54$.  But there doesn't seem to be any obvious sense in which the second is a best approximation of the first.